# How can i make widget of any ListView item?

Tags: android, listview, widget

I am working on the Note's application. In my appication i want to add the functionality like ColorNotes and Notes app. **When i long click to any listview item then it should become the widget on main screen.**

How can i build such functionality ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, in much greater detail, what "then it should become the widget on main screen" means. For example, what is "the widget"? What is a "main screen"? You might consider posting some screenshots somewhere and linking to them from your question, if you feel that they will help explain what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below link to Learn App Widget
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Use this Example for Sample this will help you to understand how will use list in Widget
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that those are screenshots of Android home screens, showing some app widgets.

You cannot cause an app widget to be added to the home screen. After all, not all home screens offer app widgets. The user would have to set up the app widget themselves.

Given that the user set up the app widget, you are welcome to populate it based on a long-click of a list row in one of your activities. [Use `AppWidgetManager` and `updateAppWidget()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget(int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews)) to push a new `RemoteViews` to the app widget based on what the user long-clicked on.

Comment: In some apps i have seen that by clicking to "Send To Home" Button the note populate to home screen as the widget. Can you provide me the specific tutorial link to build that functionality?

Comment: @NIkharBhavsar: No, sorry, I do not know of any specific tutorials for that.